# How to set Camera View rotation (without using deprecated code)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Basically, how does one do this:

```
    - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

without using deprecated code (`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`)

My app requires iOS 9, so as long as the new code is backwards compatible that far, I don't need to keep the above code. Apple suggests using `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` but I don't know how.

EDIT:

I tried (as suggested by @Matt)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                                           forName: UIApplication.willChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification,
                                           object: nil, queue: nil) { n in
        // this is where you respond
        if let userInfo = n.userInfo {
            // use the userInfo to find out what the new orientation is...
        }
    }
}
}
```

But it throws Use of undeclared identifier 'override' error because it's in swift.

Comment: @matt thanks anyways for your help.

Comment: On the other hand, since you're using this ancient language, you can figure it out by using my ancient book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_receiving_a_built_in_notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Apple DTS, this code accomplishes the same (I confirmed myself as well)

```
- (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) || UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)) {
        [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)deviceOrientation];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to mix objc with swift, otherwise you need to convert matt's code to objc, for example like below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDeviceOrientationChange) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)handleDeviceOrientationChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not trying to mix languages. That looks good-- do I need to remove the observer? or alternatively, is there a way to do it without using an observer? Thanks again.